# SUMIFS + TODAY in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sumifs

I've set up a form for my sellers so they can report contacts done every day. Results look like this:

[image: screenshot]

I want to set up a dashboard that will tell me daily, monthly and total progress in a glance. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

My SUMIFS are looking like this:

```
=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!D:D;'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C;$B4)
```

Now I need to input a new condition so it will only sum results whose dayvalue is equal to today.

I would normally use

```
 =SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!D:D,'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C, $B4, 'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A,"="&TODAY())
```

but Google Sheets has a different way of treating the SUMIFS function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's problem with how Google sheets works, you have times in with the dates, so they won't be deemed to be equal to today(). You can make it work by using two conditions on column A, `>= today` and `< tomorrow`, that will give you all times on today's date, e.g. like this:

`=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!D:D,'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C, $B4, 'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A,">="&TODAY(), 'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

That should work in both Excel and google docs